# Can there be gaps in autoignition temperatures?

Tags: thermodynamics, stability, applied-chemistry, reaction-control

I recently saw a request for solids that auto-ignite between 80C and 160C.  I can't find any, and none have yet been suggested.

Which leads me to the theoretical question: Is it possible for there to be gaps in auto-ignition temperature ranges that cannot be filled by *any* chemical?

More specifically: Supposed we're interested in auto-ignition of a chemical in a standard atmosphere (where the temperature is varied between storage and ignition).

First question: Is it true that any chemical that can auto-ignite in a given atmosphere at *some* temperature will not be shelf-stable when stored in that atmosphere at *any* temperature?  Or are there self-sustaining exothermic reactions that will not occur at all below a threshold (auto-ignition) temperature, and therefore would be indefinitely "shelf-stable"?

Second question: If shelf-stable auto-ignition is possible (or even typical), then are there any theoretical assertions that can be made about the possibility of auto-ignition temperature gaps?  E.g., if I know there is a chemical that auto-ignites at 20C, should it theoretically be possible to chemically dampen the reaction so as to raise the auto-ignition temperature arbitrarily?  Or is this just a "that's the way it is" property?  I.e., chemicals have the reactivity they have, and there's no reason to believe that you could pick an arbitrary temperature and find a compound that auto-ignites at that temperature?

Comment: +1. This is a GREAT question. If there's no answers I might put a bounty. I looked at your profile and saw you followed a proposal for a Materials Modeling Stack Exchange. If you don't mind another attempt at a Materials proposal, would you be so kind to commit to this?  https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=ZTUyZWY5OTQ1NDI4ZGVlMmU5MzM0ZThiZjNhOTRkYWFlMTA1NjM0OWEzOTZhYzlmMTBlNWQ4ZmIzYWE3MWFkN-4At28O9gekwyERVbYPhFIPwyHiajfB5BeMyrZKJaYV0 It started slow but lately it's been booming with 5 commitments/day and very soon it will reach 200.